# Having two different sets of styles in elixir in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

I'm trying to build a web app, just wanted to know I've few set of css files which are common in some pages (consider it Set1) and few page have other set of css files (Consider it Set2). I want elixir to have two set of css with different file name Set1 or Set2

Following is the code which I've tried:

```
mix.styles([

    'font-awesome.min.css',
    'simple-line-icons.min.css',
    'bootstrap.min.css',

], 'public/css/set1.css',[

    'layout/layout.css',
    'layout/custom.css'

], 'public/css/set2.css')
```

I mean is it ok to use like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can produce your 2 css files by calling the mix.styles function twice

```
mix.styles([
  'font-awesome.min.css',
  'simple-line-icons.min.css',
  'bootstrap.min.css',
], 
  'public/css/set1.css'
);


mix.styles([
  'layout/layout.css',
  'layout/custom.css'
], 
  'public/css/set2.css'
);
```